# Whatsapp backup: Unable to move from windows phone to android

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, windows-mobile

Following instructions found on WhatsApp FAQs I created a backup folder on my SD card of my old windows-based phone.

I tried to restore chat history on my new Android phone (LG Leon), with no success. I did the following steps:

1. removed previous WhatsApp installation on Android
2. put the sd card with the backup files (files are in SD card in the WhatsApp/WinPhoneBackup folder)
3. reinstalled WhatsApp
4. reactivated WhatsApp (sms stuff) and asked to recover backup

Unfortunately there's no way to allow WhatsApp to discover the backup files. Am I doing something wrong?

Some specs:

> Source phone: Nokia Lumia 520, Whatsapp version: 2.12.266
>
> Destination phone: Lg Leon with android 5.0.1, Whatsapp version: 2.12.453

Comment: Probably WhatsApp isn't looking into your SD card. Try copying/moving backups to the `WhatsApp` directory on the internal storage.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/28060005) I got solution about your question on WhatsApp FAQ page. It says

> You cannot restore the chat history from any other phone type to Windows Phone, or from Windows Phone to another phone type.

This question is possible duplicate of [this.](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9214/transfer-whatsapp-from-android-to-windows-phone#)

Comment: That is not the whole truth!
There exists ways doing that! But not officially supported by WhatsApp.com

Answer (score 1):

Biased comment (I'm the developer): Winwazzapmigrator does exactly that. It transfers windows phone whatsapp to Android. Check it out https://www.winwazzapmigrator.com

Comment: It this (paid) app the one and only way doing so?
Since WhatsApp has announced that WhatsApp on Windows Phone will stop working September 2019 (even the platform itself continue 

I'll expect that WhatsApp offers an way of moving! Currently moving from Windows Phone to Android and all Apps (except WhatsApp!!!) it is/was easy ...

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the file PATH is different in both Windows Phone/mobile and Android for WhatsApp data, also the formats are seems to be different from each other. This is reason there no option as of now to restore WhatsApp data from a Windows Phone/mobile to Android or vise versa.

WhatsApp should maintain a same file PATH and file format for any platform and should allow it's user to restore their data from any platform to another.

Comment: No, it could be simple if the Windows Phone WhatsApp offers backup to Google Drive. But it offers backup only to OneDrive. Also restore on Adnroid is not possible from OneDrive ....