# Can I open Whatsapp backup messages from Nokia C7 on Android phone?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I have a backup files from older phone (`Nokia C7`) where Whatsapp is not supported anymore. These files are stored in `data/wa`: `MsgStore.bak.1, MsgStore.bak.2, MsgStore.bak.3`, and I have there very important message which I would like to open it again. So I was thinking if it's possible to install Whatsapp on Android phone, add those backup files in storage and recover it back to readable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as explained here [Whatsapp backup: Unable to move from windows phone to android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137255/whatsapp-backup-unable-to-move-from-windows-phone-to-android)

You can try the PC software or other methods mentioned here [4 Ways to Transfer Data from Windows phone to Android for Free](https://mobiletrans.wondershare.com/transfer/4-ways-to-transfer-data-from-windows-phone-to-android-device-for-free.html)

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow (die hard) veteran user of Symbian OS, I can tell there is a solution (or a trick) to log in back to WhatsApp in order to access your messages.

> Simply change the date to 1/6/2017 on Symbian phone which will allow it to run WhatsApp without that pop-up.

As we can expect this trick won't last long, so as soon you you log in, get your classified chats send them (or forward them to android device, and save them there.  All the best :)

Comment: Ok, that phone is not with me right now but it is has it my friend, so basically he should just change a date in a settings, reboot a phone and that's it, yeah?

Comment: No need to reboot, he should change date in Settings, and opening WhatsApp he should instantly access old chats. I tried and tested and confirmed   it to be working :)

Comment: I'm one step further so now it will open whatsapp and prompt to enter phone number to register an account, but it will stuck at 'initializing'...

Comment: Try restarting your device, AFAIK you should access your old messages without having to verify your number again, at least thats how I did it on my device, I think for your situation after restarting you should prevent a data connection, so this way you go straight to old chats